# Weak convergence of discrete random variables to a continuous variable

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory

The question is from Billingsley. $X_n \in \{\gamma_n+k\delta_n; k\in N\}, \delta_n>0$. Suppose $\delta_n\rightarrow 0$ and $k_n$ is an integer varying with n s.t. $\gamma_n+k_n\delta_n\rightarrow x$ and $P(\gamma_n+k_n\delta_n)\delta_n^{-1}\rightarrow f(x)$ where $f$ is the density of a random variable $X$. Show that $X_n\rightarrow X$ weakly.

My attempt: $X_n\rightarrow X$ weakly $\iff \int gd\mu_n\rightarrow \int gd\mu $ where $g$ is continuous, bounded and I think it is enough to be compactly supported. $\mu_n$ is the distribution of $X_n$.

So need to show $\sum_n \delta_ng(\gamma_n+k\delta_n)P\{X_n=\gamma_n+k\delta_n\}\delta_n^{-1} \rightarrow \int g(x)f(x)dx$ which I guess follows from Riemmanian sum. Since g is bounded, we can move the limit inside but I am having trouble transitioning from $k$ to $k_n$ because we know $g(\gamma_n+k_n\delta_n)\rightarrow g(x)$ and $P\{X_n=\gamma_n+k_n\delta_n\}\delta_n^{-1} \rightarrow f(x)$ i.e. we have convergence for a particular sequence $\{k_n\}$. We need to show convergence $\forall k$, don't we? Any ideas? and thanks!
[image]

Comment: I would try to use the so-called "(sub)-subsequence property" i.e. $X_n$ converges weakly to $X$ if and only if: for any subsequence of $X_n$, there exists a further subsequence that converges weakly to $X$.

Comment: Thanks, I was thinking of using one of the subsequence properties but the problem is that we have convergence along a particular subsequence $k_n$ along which $\gamma_n+k_n\delta_n\rightarrow x$ and $P(\gamma_n+k_n\delta_n)\delta_n^{-1}\rightarrow f(x)$. So I'm not sure how to tackle that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've phrased one of the conditions slightly incorrectly. As stated, it is unclear what the variable $x$ has to do with anything. The condition should read something like: "Suppose that whenever $k_n$ is a sequence of integers with $\gamma_n+k_n\delta_n\to x$, then $P[X_n=\gamma_n+k_n\delta_n]\delta_n^{-1}\to f(x)$".

With this in mind, here is a sketch to prove the assertion. First replace the discrete $X_n$ with a "histogrammed" version, call it $X'_n$, which for each integer $k$ places mass $P[X_n=\gamma_n+k\delta_n]$ uniformly over the *interval* of width $\delta_n$ centered at $\gamma_n+k\delta_n$. (Since the density of $X'_n$ is constant over the interval, this constrains the density's height over that interval to be...) You then prove that $X'_n$ converges in distribution to $X$ (applying the result of the exercise directly previous to this one) by showing that the density of $X'_n$ converges pointwise to the density of $X$. To show pointwise convergence, let $x$ be fixed. There exists for each $n$ an integer $k_n$ such that $x$ lies in the interval centered at $\gamma_n + k_n\delta_n$. Argue that this defines a sequence $(k_n)$ for which $\gamma_n + k_n\delta_n\to x$, and the result follows.

Having demonstrated this, you next write the original $X_n$ as $h_n(X'_n)$ for a suitable sequence of functions $h_n$ that converge pointwise to the identity function $h(x):=x$. Then argue that $h_n(X'_n)$ converges in distribution to $h(X)$. (See the exercise two previous to this one.)

Comment: Thanks! I have proved that if densities converge pointwise, then distributions converge weakly but I don't understand why the density of $X_n^{'}$ is $P(\gamma_n+k_n\delta_n)\delta_n^{-1}$? For a given $x$, which is equal to $lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}(\gamma_n+k_n\delta_n)$, I don't understand how that implies density of $X_n^{'} = P(\gamma_n+k_n\delta_n)\delta_n^{-1}$? Appreciate a hint.

Comment: @manifolded I have added some more detail to the second paragraph.

Comment: Thanks for a detailed explanation, understood it now. Last question, in the third paragraph, $X_n^{'}\xrightarrow{w}X$ and $h_n(x_n^{'})\rightarrow h(x)$ ptwise $\implies$ $X_n\xrightarrow{w} X$. Why does $h_n(x_n^{'})\rightarrow h(x)$ ptwise? Do we choose $h_n$ s.t. $h_n(x_n^{'}) = \gamma_n + k_n\delta _n$, $h(x)=x$ and thus $ \gamma_n + k_n\delta _n\rightarrow x$? Thanks :)

Comment: @manifolded You have to argue that $h_n(x)\to h(x)$ for each $x$, which is much simpler than worrying about $X_n$ or $X'_n$ or $\gamma_n$, etc.

Comment: Thanks, but to show ptwise convergence, I'm trying to understand what does $h_n$ look like. The support of $X_n^{'}$ is $R$, so $h_n:R\rightarrow \{\gamma_n+k\delta _n\}$ and $h_n (x) = \gamma _n+k\delta _n$, right? Where $k$ is s.t. $\gamma _n+k\delta _n$ is the closest to $x$.

Comment: @manifolded Correct. Your best bet is to draw a picture of $h_n$ for a given $n$. Note that for a given $n$, both $\gamma_n$ and $\delta_n$ are constant; only $k$ is free to vary, and it varies over the integers.

Comment: Perfect, thank you very much!

Comment: Hey, sorry for asking this again. In the picture above, $h_n(x)=\gamma_n + k\delta_n$ but how do we know that $\gamma_n + k\delta_n\rightarrow x$ to claim that $h_n (X_n^{'})\rightarrow h(X)$ pointwise? Thanks.

Comment: @manifolded As you stated previously, you choose $k_n$ s.t. $\gamma_n+k_n\delta_n$ is closest to $x$.  What is the furthest apart that these two quantities could be? (Keep in mind that the points $\{\gamma_n +k\delta_n\}$ are equally spaced.)

Comment: True, as $|\gamma_n+k_n \delta_n - x| \leq \delta_n$ and $\delta_n\rightarrow 0$. You are the best :)